# LambdaInvokerFactory Unsupported Operation: Cannot evaluate

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am invoking an AWS Lambda function directly from my Android app. I have the Request class:

```
private class MyRequest
{
    String param;
    public SetIdentityRequest() {}
    public SetIdentityRequest(String param) {this.param = param;}
    public String getParam() { return param; }
    public void setParam(String param) { this.param = param; }
}
```

I don't need any values returned, so I don't have a Response class. I tried making an empty one in case that was causing my problem, but I got a lot more errors.

My interface class:

```
private interface MyLambda
{
    @LambdaFunction
    void myLambda(MyRequest req);
}
```

And finally my code for calling it:

```
LambdaInvokerFactory factory = new LambdaInvokerFactory(getApplicationContext(), Regions.US_EAST_1, credentialsProvider);
MyLambda lambda = factory.build(MyLambda.class);
lambda.myLambda(new MyRequest(someString));
```

Now, the lambda does actually go through and execute properly, so this isn't a dealbreaking kind of error; but I've been seeing when I step through it in debug that the line that has `factory.build` gets an error `Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.myapp.$Proxy1.toString()`. What is this error about? Do I need to worry about it? What do I need to do to stop getting this error?

Comment: Hello! Can you confirm the code for constructing the factory object compiled? It should be `Regions.US_EAST_1` however you don't have the plurality (`Regions`). Can you post the complete stacktrace? What is the frequency of this exception?

Comment: Yes, it was a transcription error here in the question; it's Regions in the original code. I have updated the question.

I don't have a stacktrace for where the error is actually occurring; the build method that is reporting the error still returns successfully, but the debugger tells me it threw an exception, but I don't have an exception object to analyze. This seems to be happening every time I slow down the debug to look at it.

Comment: You can get the stacktrace from Logcat. Without a stacktrace it is difficult to analyze the issue further.